# Compositing effects not applying in final render 3.6

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

[image]

[image]

Hello, I changed the color slightly when compositing, but when it renders it still shows the original image. Im not sure what im doing wrong, this is from an image sequence I rendered.